# Can't change attribute in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I trying to dynamically change bootstrap popover content. I shoud use botstrap 5.1.3 and there is no setContent() method like in newer versions. I try to do this with jQuery script:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#item-datalist').attr({
        'data-bs-toggle': "popover",
        'data-bs-trigger': "manual"
    });
    $('#count').attr({
      'data-bs-toggle': "popover",
      'data-bs-trigger': "manual"
    });
    $('#item-datalist').click(function() {
      $(this).css('border-color', '#001427');
      let attr = $(this).attr('data-bs-toggle');
      if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr === 'popover') {
        $(this).popover('hide');
      }
    })
    $('#count').click(function() {
      $(this).css('border-color', '#001427');
      let attr = $(this).attr('data-bs-toggle');
      if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr === 'popover') {
        $(this).popover('hide');
      }
    })
  })
  $('.form').submit(function (e) {
    var datalist_value = $('#item-datalist').val();
    var count_value = $('#count').val();
    var datalist_valid = false;
    var count_valid = false;
    if (datalist_value == '') {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#item-datalist').css('border-color', '#F24236');
      $('#item-datalist').attr('data-bs-content', 'Поле не должно быть пустым');
      $('#item-datalist').popover('show');
    } else {
      id = $('#items [value="' + datalist_value + '"]').data('value');
      if (id != null) {
        datalist_valid = true;
      } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#item-datalist').css('border-color', '#F24236');
        $('#item-datalist').attr('data-bs-content', 'Не совпадает ни с одним наименованием');
        $('#item-datalist').popover('show');
      }
    }
  if (Math.floor(count_value) == count_value && $.isNumeric(count_value) && count_value > 0) {
    count_valid = true;
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#count').css('border-color', '#F24236');
    $('#count').attr('data-bs-content', 'Введите целое, положительное число, больше 0');
    $('#count').popover('show');
  }
  if (datalist_valid === true && count_valid === true) {
    $('#item-datalist').val(id);
  }
  })
```

**why this line didn't work:**
    $('#item-datalist').attr('data-bs-content', 'Не совпадает ни с одним наименованием');
**, but others two:**
    $('#item-datalist').css('border-color', '#F24236');
    $('#item-datalist').popover('show');
**works fine?**

How can I repair script?

Comment: Can you add some sample HTML to go with the example? ... Use the `<>` icon on the toolbar to create a runnable fiddle example. Jquery can be selected from the left side of the runnable editor, though jquery 3.3.1 is the highest available, but it should work based on what you have.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @PaulT. I have update my question and create JSFiddle for example [link](https://jsfiddle.net/2kc8s5b3/2/). In this form, when item field is empty, should be shown popover with text 'Field should not be emplty' and when there is some text in this field which didn't match with any option in datalist, should be shown popover with text 'Don't match with any option', but popover content didn't chanched with this code $('#item-datalist').attr('data-bs-content', 'Don\'t match with any option').

Comment: @SigarevAndrey ... I see what you mean, but not sure why, I'll have to tinker with the fiddle a bit more.